# print out Coordinates from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, coordinates, println

Hi i have working code but i would like to print out the coordinates. there is a hashmap that holds Coordinates and Strings. there is a class for Coordinates to allow me to put Coordinates in but when i try to print out it gets confused im clearly not doing something right. Thanks for looking

```
public class XYTest {
static class Coords {
    int x;
    int y;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Coords c = (Coords) o;
        return c.x == x && c.y == y;
    }

    public Coords(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return new Integer(x + "0" + y);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    HashMap<Coords, String> map = new HashMap<Coords, String>();

    map.put(new Coords(65, 72), "Dan");

    map.put(new Coords(68, 78), "Amn");
    map.put(new Coords(675, 89), "Ann");

    System.out.println(map.size());
}
}
```

Comment: You have to override toString in your Coordinates class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `toString()` in your Coords class.

```
static class Coords {
    int x;
    int y;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Coords c = (Coords) o;
        return c.x == x && c.y == y;
    }

    public Coords(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return new Integer(x + "0" + y);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return x + ";" + y;
    }
}
```

What is confusing you is something like this:

```
XYTest.Coords@3e25a5
```

What is this? It is the result of the original `toString()` method. Here is what it does:

```
return getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

So, overriding it with your own code will get rid of the confusing output :)

---

Please note that your having great hash-collisions. A much better hashCode() implementation would be:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return (x << 16) ^ y;
}
```

To demonstrate your bad hash code: Some collisions:

- (0,101) and (1,1)
- (44,120) and (44012,0)

Comment: ive tried this fix but doesnt work it doesnt seem to like public void. then when i try to change it to public string the hashmap doesnt allow it

Comment: do i have to change something when creating the Hashmap?

Comment: dont worry realised what to do i didnt put it in the map.put function but put it in the println function thanks for the help

Comment: @Djchunky123: Oooops, you were right. I made a mistake, of course the `void` should be replaced by `String`.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn said override toString()

```
class Coords {
....

public String toString(){
   return this.x + "-" + this.y;
 }
....
```

}

...and

```
  public static void main(String []args){
```

....

```
    map.put(new Coords(65, 72).toString(), "Dan");
```

....

```
  }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help but your slightly off as the Hashmap wont allow tostring in the map.put function you use it in the print function instead thanks for the help :)